# XSD: How to add a restriction on attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have XSD schema with `xs:attributeGroup` element.

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="userAttrGroup">
    <xs:attribute name="age"          type="xs:integer" use="required"/>

    <!-- Should be at least one of {status | address-type | country} -->

    <xs:attribute name="status"       type="xs:string"  use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="country"      type="xs:string"  use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="address-type" type="xs:string"  use="optional"/>    
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

I want to add a restriction on three attributes. It should be at least one of next set `{status, address-type, country}`.

Is it possible to do that in XSD?

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.1 you can use an assertion to express context-sensitive constraints of that kind; in XSD 1.0, I don't know a way to do what you say you want to do.